# In a forced marriage, is sex obligatory for the woman?

Tags: nikah, women, sex, husband-wife

If you are in a forced marriage in Islam, is it still necessary to perform sexual intercourse with your husband/wife? If you are not happy or give consent to having any sexual activities performed on you, doesn't that count as rape?

Is it allowed for the woman to prevent sexual intercourse on the night of the wedding and weeks to follow simply because she doesn't want to have sex.

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/312/is-a-woman-required-to-have-sex-with-her-husband-whenever-he-requests-it?rq=1

Comment: From a logical and Islamic perspective it's all considered to be raping.

Answer (score 7):

1. Marriage without both man's and woman's consent is void.

   > **The woman and the man should be willing to enter into a matrimonial alliance. If, however, the woman ostensibly displays hesitation while
   >   giving her consent, but it is known that in her heart, she is
   >   agreeable to the marriage, the marriage is in order.**

   However, if any of them were forced into matrimony then they give their contest after the marriage has been pronounced, their marriage is in order, although it is better that the formula of marriage be recited again.
2. A woman with whom permanent marriage is conducted should submit herself to her husband's sexual desire. she is not allowed to prevent him from having sexual intercourse without justifiable excuses according to Islamic laws (like being in the state of Hayz)
3. If at the time of conducting permanent marriage, no deadline is set for paying "Mahr", the wife can prevent her husband from having sexual intercourse whether he is able to pay it or not. But if she ONCE agrees to have sexual intercourse without taking Mahr, then her husband has sexual intercourse with her, she should not prevent him afterwards without justifiable excuses.

**source: [Islamic Laws](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/)**

Answer (score 2):

First of all, forced marriages are not valid. Read this: http://islamqa.info/en/47439

But if you accept the marriage and the marriage is valid, then you have to obey your husband about the issue you mentioned. Read this: http://islamqa.info/en/9602

Answer (score 1):

marriage is for protecting men and women. love between men and women governs. islam says be kind with your wife. an also says control your temper. if wife and husnabd love each other and respect each other,they never do force for sex.remember islam is a kind religious. and come for improve our temper and life.