# What does Quran and the Hadith say against abusing women?

Tags: women, fiqh, reference-request

I am searching for some references (preferably with background history) against abusing women. What is Islam's stands against teasing/sexually harassing or abusing women? What is the punishment for this?

Comment: Maybe you'll find my answer here helpful http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27525/wifes-tamkin-and-marital-rape/27526#27526

Comment: good answer. I was searching for something more generic like teasing or rapeing someone who is neither your wife nor you have any rights over her.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a scholar, so I don't know of any specific text but I know of a few ayahs and hadith which teach mercy to all the creation and to women specifically (I will paraphrase them but I am sure the references are easily obtainable through sheikh Google).

> "And We have not sent you except as a Mercy to all creation" - [Qur'an 21:107](http://quran.com/21:107)
>
> "Have Mercy to those on earth and the One in the heavens will have mercy on you"- Abdullah ibn Amr ibn al-'As [Sunan Abi Dawud 4941] ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/169))
>
> "The best of you are the best to their wives and I am the best to my wives"- Ibn 'Abbas [Sunan Ibn Majah, Vol. 3, Book 9, Hadith 1977] ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/urn/1262960))

There is also no instance of the Prophet (saw) ever sexually harassing or abusing women. On the contrary all of the narrations seem to indicate that he treated the women in his life with the utmost compassion, love, dignity and respect.

Moreover, Islam in general teaches you to be good and merciful to all those around you, and the better you treat God's creation the better you will be in His estimation.

Whereas abuse and harassment is a clear manifestation of the ego (nafs) which seeks to dominate and oppress, a clear satanic behavior. How could it ever be pleasing to God, and thus in any way Islamic?

God Knows best.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Islam gives respect to women.  Before Islam, people used to treat women like slaves and wouldn't marry har if she become widow. Islam gives women a respectful place in society, and gives order to man not even to put a glance over a girl:

> Imam Ja'far al-Sadiq (a.s.) says:
>
> "A young man from the Ansar met a woman is Madina. At that time, women used to wear a veil, so he looked at her while she was coming toward him. Men she passed by he continued looking after her until he entered one of the alleys. He continued looking as he passed along the alley until a bone on a wall slashed his face and the woman passed out of sight. Then, unexpectedly, he saw blood flowing over his clothes and chest. He said, 'I must go and inform the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w.) about the incident.' When the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w.) saw him in this condition he said, 'What happened?' When he informed the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w.) about the event in details, the angel Gabriel (a.s.) came down with this verse:
>
> 'Say to the believing men that they should lower their gaze and guard their private parts. That is purer for them. Truly Allah is Cognizant of what they do.' (Holy Qur’an, 24:30)
>
> Wasa'il al-Shi'ah, vol. 9, p, 63.  ([Al-Islam.org](https://www.al-islam.org/islamic-hijab-al-balagh/what-holy-quran-and-traditions-say-about-woman-and-social-life))

and

> The Messenger of Allah (s.a.w.) said:
>
> "Guard yourselves from six things and I am your surety for Paradise:
> when you speak, speak the truth; perform when you promise; discharge
> your trust,. and guard your private parts (except from your wives);
> cast down your eyes; with hold your hand from committing aggression or
> forbidden things".
>
> Ibid., p. 35, 33, Tuhaf al-Uqol an aali al- Rasool, Al-Harrani, p, 23. ([Al-Islam.org](https://www.al-islam.org/islamic-hijab-al-balagh/what-holy-quran-and-traditions-say-about-woman-and-social-life))

I'm not a scholar, otherwise I would give you more references. Islam strictly forbids abusing woman or sexual harassment.