# How to find what we want on Quran?

Tags: quran

I am non-Islam, but I like to learn Islam. But I don't know that how to search something on Quran.

Eg:

I read [Is a woman required to have sex with her husband whenever he requests it?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/312/is-a-woman-required-to-have-sex-with-her-husband-whenever-he-requests-it).

Most upvoted answer stared as "Yes that's true.".

So I want to find on Quran where it was mentioned?

Comment: It’s Qur’an 4:34. To search the Qur’an, you can go to Quran.com and use the search feature. I also have a Quran app on my phone. Or you can just use Google and search for “quran (topic)”.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Is it means? I mean https://quran.com/4/34 doesn't meen something like that? I mean it does not mean that a woman required to have sex with her husband whenever he requests it

Comment: It says "righteous women are devoutly obedient".  Indeed, it doesn't directly say a woman is required to have sex, but it's the relevant part of the Qur'an.  From here, ahadith such as "If a husband calls his wife to his bed... and she refuses and causes him to sleep in anger, the angels will curse her till morning" ([Sahih al-Bukhari 3237](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/48)) are used to guide how it's interpreted.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Thanks... I am talking this with a Islam friend of mine. He asked that always prove this with quran. He is telling that 4:34 does not mean anything like that he said other reference is fake and it is not quran....

Comment: The Islam laws also from the hadeeths not just Quran

Answer (score 4):

Searching the Qur'an can be done as most other online text documents:

1. You can search the Qur'an using a web search engine.  E.g. [`quran patience and prayer`](http://cn.bing.com/search?q=quran%20patience%20and%20prayer).  This will often give the surah and ayah numbers (in this example 2:153), and we can go to the URL [`https://quran.com/2/153`](https://quran.com/2/153).
2. Use the search function at Quran.com.  E.g. [`patience and prayer`](https://quran.com/search?q=patience%20and%20prayer).
3. I have a Qur'an app on my iPhone: [Quran by Quran.com](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quran-by-quran-com-%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A2%D9%86/id1118663303?mt=8), Mohamad Afifi.  It's searchable.

Knowing what to search for is the challenge: it takes time to become familiar with how the Qur'an (or one of its translations) is formulated.  Nothing is better here than actually having read the Qur'an, so you're aware of its contents.

It's important to understand that much of what's in the Qur'an cannot just be taken at face value.  For example, [Qur'an 4:119](https://quran.com/4/119) quotes Satan saying *I will command them so they will change the creation of Allah*.  Then a question might arise: does this apply to circumcision?  (When we need to be careful.)

To help understand how we apply the instructions in the Qur'an, we use [ahadith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith), [tafsir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafsir), and [fatawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatwa).

Generally, if you web search for `fatwa [topic I'm interested in]` you'll find some fatawa that discuss the topic, giving relevant references to the Qur'an (and ahadith).  In this example, we might search for [`fatwa sex with her husband whenever he requests it`](http://cn.bing.com/search?q=fatwa%20sex%20with%20her%20husband%20whenever%20he%20requests%20it) and the top hit is [an IslamWeb fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=100429).  It doesn't give an exact source, but it links to [another IslamWeb fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=E&Id=84944) which gives the hadith:

> The Prophet (Sallallahu Alaihi wa Sallam) said: "If a woman spends the night deserting her husband's bed (does not sleep with him), then the angels send their curses on her till she comes back (to her husband)" [Reported by Imams al-Bukhari and Muslim ].

The hadith sources al-Bukhari and Muslim can be found on Sunnah.com, and with a bit of effort, we can find those ahadith: [Sahih al-Bukhari 5194](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/67/128) and [Sahih Muslim 1436 c](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1436c).

In this example, [Qur'an 4:34](https://quran.com/4/34) says *righteous women are devoutly obedient*, which doesn't say exactly "the wife must have sex on demand".  Instead, it is interpreted more generally as an instruction for the wife to *obey her husband in what is permissible* ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=%2084120)).