# Real meaning of loyality to husband

Tags: fiqh, husband-wife, definitions

One Islamic hadith says that loyality to your husband after marriage is one of the most essential duties for a female to perform.sometimes it also indicattes that you have to always prioritize your husbands choice over everything. So my question is if your husband wants to initiate physical relationship although you are not ready for it,mentally or physically.
Is that mandatory to get into physical relationship with your husband???
If consent of a lady matters or not in this matter???
Or Islam always asks you to satisfy your husband even though you solely deny it???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "obey" mean in "righteous women are devoutly obedient" in Qur'an 4:34?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31474/what-does-obey-mean-in-righteous-women-are-devoutly-obedient-in-quran-434) and also [What does being an obedient wife really mean?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35201/what-does-being-an-obedient-wife-really-mean) and [Is a woman required to have sex with her husband whenever he requests it?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/312/is-a-woman-required-to-have-sex-with-her-husband-whenever-he-requests-it)

Answer (score -2):

I think woman should obey a good husband, if a man force his wife to do something that she can't for now (having sex but she's sick), I don't consider him as a good husband.

LA YOQALIFO ALLAHO NAFSSANE ILLA WOSAAHA

Sorry for my English, it's not my native language :)